# Add blank row at the end of a WPF datagrid conditionally (without using a default parameterless ctor)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to add a BLANK row at the end of a WPF 4.0 DataGrid *conditionally* (not via code-behind directly). I have tried the following  but in vain -

I have tried to do get the IEditableCollectionView like this and operate upon that interface:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myObservableCollection) as IEditableCollectionView
```

But, that does not work as intended because one of the factors for the **CanAddNew** property to be true is to add a default constructor to the underlying object of the collection (to which the Grid is bound to).

**Problem**: If I add a default constructor, then the grid always adds a blank row. I want to add upon a *condition* (checking a bool value) and not always. How do I do that without using a default parameterless constructor for my ViewModel class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/wpf/thread/09398b8a-8356-4ca6-9216-a45fc95227d8) now - 
I add an empty item into my Collection based on the condition. Then, if user edits the empty item of the collection, I add one more empty row programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind CanAddNew to a property in your model, then you can set it to true/false depends on your condition:

```
   <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="{Binding Path=YourBooleanProperty}"/>
```

Comment: `CanAddNew` is a getter on IEditableCollectionView (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionview.canaddnew.aspx). Can you please show with some small example ?

Comment: Its a property of the DataGrid

Comment: Can you provide the msdn link for this property pls ?

Comment: This does not work. You can try that yourself by adding a `parameterless constructor` in your ViewModel (do not add any blank ctor).